# Why this class implements two interfaces, where one already extends from a common parent?

Tags: java

Class AbstractInterruptibleChannel implements both InterruptibleChannel and its super interface Channel.

Is there any reason behind to do this?

or What should be the advantage of this?

[image: Diagram]

Comment: This is some sort of an undocumented convention followed throughout the JDK implementation. For example, `ArrayList` extends `AbstractList` as well as implements `List`, even though `AbstractList` is already declared to be an implementation of `List`. The idea seems to be that if someone removes the `implements ...` part from the parent class, a compile-time error will be thrown since one or more child classes explicitly require an implementation of one of more interface being removed.

Comment: It's just for clarity, IMO

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, this is actually redundant.

The only reason to do that: you are maybe concerned that the sub interface is changed at a future point - to no longer extend that other interface.

By explicitly putting down both interfaces you are protected against that change (and yes, that class says "implements" for both interfaces).

But still, this is a rather uncommon, surprising construct, nothing I would be using.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is the same.
I think that the intention is the information for developers that don't need to enter in the absract class definition to understand that the interface is indirectly implemented.
`AbstractInterruptibleChannel` is 2 things : a chanel (`Channel`) and an interruptible one (`InterruptibleChannel`). Declaring both interfaces explicitly emphasizes it.
For custom classes it may seem just redundant and helpless but for jdk classes which the source code is browsered and read millions times, it is probably not.